# Inject a annotation-based requirement in a Symfony2 controller

Tags: php, api, symfony

I am currently writing a REST API using Symfony2. I started using Symfony2 one month ago and i'm currently facing a technical difficulty.

While writing my API I wanted to rate limit the API calls by IP addresses or by user (i.e if the user is logged in I'm using his id, a timestamp and his IP address to keep a trace of his connection, if he's not logged in, I just save his IP address and a timestamp in my database).
To do this I wrote a service implementing `VoterInterface` and who's called by Symfony everytime a user accesses a controller and checks whether he didn't exceed the API rate limit by hour or by day (they're both hardcoded)). This works fine until now.

But I want something more customizable and scalable, I would like to set up for each controller their own limit so I could control and change easily my API rate limit for each one. My idea is to use an annotation like the ones you can use with the `JMSSecurityExtraBundle` and specify on the top of each of my controllers something like :

```
/**
 * My API - UserController::registerAction
 *
 * @RateLimit(hour="200", day="2000")
 */
public function registerAction($format)
```

And then retrieve the annotation informations in my rate limiter class to fill the limits informations.
The problem is I didn't manage to find how and I need some help. My solution works, I just need something more powerfull. I already thought about storing these informations in a YAML file or in a database, but this is not a good solution to me since it creates an unnecessary dependency between my controllers and a persistence.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [AOP Bundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSAopBundle) — it provides the means for doing what you want.